# Object before "me" in an array

Tags: swift

I'm iterating over `var cards : [Card]` and running functions on each entry. Some of those entries modify the card before it.

1) Is there an easy way to say "the previous object"?

2) Is there an easy way to say "my index within the collection"? Then I could use that index-1 to get the previous card.

Right now I'm looping, but Swift has surprised me with easier solutions I did not know about so I'm hoping that's the case for these.

**Update:**
Here's the basic code. The `Deck` consists of `Card`s, each one describing a bit of 3D geometry. So I have a method called Draw that takes the `Deck` as parameter `d` and then does this:

```
for g in d.cards {
    switch g.info["type"] ?? "" {
        case "GA" : arc(g)
        case "GE" : ground(g)
        case "GH" : helix(g)
        case "GW" : wire(g)
        case "SP" : patch(g)
        case "SM" : multi(g)
        case "GM" : duplicate(g, deck:d)
        case "GR" : cylinder(g, deck:d)
        default : continue
    }
}
```

Now some of those cards, like GM for instance, duplicate the previous `Card`. So I previously looped through the entire `Deck` again looking for `g` and then taking the previous one. This is sub-optimal! @vadian's solution below neatly solved that problem.

Comment: Could you describe more your algorithm? It's a bit hard to say which solution will be the best if you are not specific.

Comment: Yes Sulthan, I should have expanded on this a lot. I'm updating the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enumerate` function provides both the item and the index

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

for (index, item) in array.enumerate() { // Swift 3: enumerated()
  print(item)
  if index != 0 { print(array[index - 1]) }
  // or – more sophisticated – array[index.predecessor()]
}
```

Comment: I had not come across this before, but it seems like the solution to a lot of little problems. Thanks!